# How to get Quicklook to open shellscript as source

Tags: shell, script, quicklook

I typically have a set of shell scripts with no extensions. Something like:

```
git-completion
git-flow
git-addremove
..etc..
```

All these script are written in bash. When I use Quicklook on them it shows a basic preview. The correct behavior for this script executables should be to display their source code.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [QLStephen](http://whomwah.github.com/qlstephen/) does what you're asking for. (And boy, it sure has a handsome name)

> QLStephen is an Apple OSX QuickLook plugin that lets you view plain text files without a file extension. It is useful for reading files like:
>
> - README
> - INSTALL
> - CHANGELOG
> - Makefile
> - Rakefile
> - CapFile

[image: Screen shot of QLStephen viewing an executable "git-test" file]